# VBA function to copy text from a single un-moving cell to paste to another cell, moving down one cell each paste/loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a worksheet that will eventually be used for route optimization using an original base address and a list of locations. I currently have a macro that uses google maps api that will list distances and duration from the origin address to all of the addresses on the list. I am trying to pull the shortest duration found using the google maps api and have the associated address be used as the new origin so I can compare the distances and duration again. I have the worksheet setup so that the shortest duration address replaces the previous origin address, but I need to be able to copy and paste each of the new origin addresses into their own cells to essentially make a list of the order that they are used.

Basically, consider that cell G16 is where the first origin address is stored and after the first run of the distance/duration macro G16 will update to whatever address is the least furthest away from the origin address, therefor becoming the new origin. I then need to copy that origin address to cell G18 and repeat the distance/duration macro with each subsequent address from G16 being copied down 1 cell/row at a time. ie, the 1st address is copied to G18, the 2nd to G19, 3rd to G20, until all of the addresses are listed. The number of addresses is also variable and changes with each week so the range is inconsistent.

Please let me know if this makes any sense as it is kind of complicated to explain. Thank you!

Comment: What specifically is giving you problems?

Comment: I have very very limited experience working with VBA so I tried to record a macro to do the job but so far I have just been able to copy and paste the value but I want it to move/paste down one cell each time the macro is used. Here is what I have so far:

   
 Range("G16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G19").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G16").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
End Sub

Comment: `Range("G16").Copy Cells(Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` will copy G16 to the next free cell below.

Comment: That's nearly perfect! Thanks man! Only thing is that the G16 cell that I am copying from is a formula and I am trying to copy/paste just the value that the formula reaches, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Cells(Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("G16").Value
```